# Error while trying to remove a ppa (with ppa-purge) which itself throws an error

Tags: ppa

I tried to add a ppa to control the heat issues of Ubuntu 20.04 but it threw an error. So I then tried to remove it, which again throws the same error.

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/unstable
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: I'd normally fix with a text editor (or terminal), but you can use *software sources* and many other GUI tools too.

Comment: @guiverc hm not sure, it suggests using ppa-purge with does not work, and the comment says that the solution was to accept the broken ppa in some settings menu?
and its possible to do that manually in a file? where is the ppa file located? and what are the risks if I remove some lines not understanding what I'm doing?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1163224/1238913
ppa-purge did not work but `sudo add-apt-repository --remove` did

Comment: If you haven't actually installed something from there due to errors then there's no point in using ppa-purge. Removing the PPA is enough.

Comment: @ChanganAuto ah so ppa-purge removes things connected to the ppa and not the ppa entry to the ppa-list/registry?

Comment: The main sources are found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` however generally ones users have added are found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (ie. I mentioned terminal/editor, you can edit/change/remove anything in that directory as they were all added post-install and are not Ubuntu repositories, but 3rd party; ie. not critical for your base Ubuntu system)

Comment: It removes both. ppa-purge is useful to get things back to what they were before adding a given PPA and installing from it and other changes. If the added PPA didn't work then nothing was changed so removing it is enough.

Comment: Note the use of the `sources.list.d/` or "/" at the end, to signify it's a directory of entries... by default that is an empty directory on a clean Ubuntu system (filled by details added by users)

Comment: Thank you very much you two!